# how to make Background color transparent

Tags: css

How can i make a background color partially transparent with css, i want to have the background color partially showing the background image thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YHbUS.png)

```
<div id="border101"> 
    <center><img src="img/logo.jpg" height="120px"></center>
    <hr> 
    <p style="background-color: white; font-size: 20px;" align="left"> 
        Welcome to cryptofreeonline.ga we have many site in different formats. 
        We made this site with some basic help from the owners over at 
        <a href="blackccgen.ga">Blackccgen</a>
    </p> 
</div>


#border101 { 
border: 10px solid silver; 
margin-left: 100px; 
margin-right: 100px; 
border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px; 
margin-top:30px; 
height: 650px; 
background-color: #C64CD5; 
}
```

Comment: they use `background-image` what do you mean  `background color partially`?

Comment: i want background color to show as well as be able to see the image through it kinda like a tinted window

Comment: any idea how to do that

Comment: Please don't post image descriptions only. Always copy / paste your full code so that the code becomes searchable and your question stays useless in case the image link gets removed. Further reading https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/374700/why-do-people-post-code-as-images

Comment: @RichardCooper that what you mean?https://jsfiddle.net/7k8tshLy/

Comment: perfect thanks bro

Comment: i cant actually mark this as finished because you didnt put that as a answer

Comment: sorry what lol you confused me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `opacity` to `background` by using [`rgba`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_rgba.asp) (`a` is the opacity)

I convert the `hex` color to `rgb` using:https://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_converter.asp

```css
#border101 { 
border: 10px solid silver;
margin-left: 100px; 
margin-right: 100px; 
border-radius: 30px 30px 30px 30px; 
margin-top:30px; height: 650px; 
background-color: rgba(198, 76, 213,0.5); 
}
```

```html
<div id="border101"> 
    <center><img src="img/logo.jpg" height="120px"></center>
    <hr> 
    <p style="background-color: white; font-size: 20px;" align="left"> 
        Welcome to cryptofreeonline.ga we have many site in different formats. 
        We made this site with some basic help from the owners over at 
        <a href="blackccgen.ga">Blackccgen</a>
    </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this color

```
background-color:#ff341140;
```

last two number in color code is for transparency here is 40